# git/SparkleShare on Windows: UTF-8 commit message (= filename) is not displayed correctly

Tags: git, utf-8

We use [SparkleShare](https://www.sparkleshare.org/) on Windows to help non-technical editors to synchronize files to a git repository. SparkleShare puts the filename being edited/added into the git commit message. Our filenames are in UTF-8. In GitLab they are not displayed correctly. [See an example here](https://gitlab.com/pninim.org/pninim/-/commit/ad5648e0cf7122aab59bf9e18bf3e39da32bb420).

I tried to set following settings in Git Bash, but it didn't help:

```
git config --global core.quotepath off
git config --global --unset i18n.logoutputencoding
git config --global --unset i18n.commitencoding
```

Any ideas what can be done to have the commit message displayed properly?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this SparkleShare bug:  https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/issues/1753

This issue is still open.

---

I put notes on my research here in case it is useful to others.

First of all, it should be safe to use UTF-8 in git commit messages (see [Safe to use any utf-8 character in git commit messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886871/safe-to-use-any-utf-8-character-in-git-commit-messages))

However, I couldn't read the commit messages in   https://gitlab.com/pninim.org/pninim.git

I tried using the latest Git (git version 2.26.2), and a console with a TrueType font (Lucida Console).

Instead of Hebrew characters, I saw things like:

```
+ ‘׳×׳<U+009C>׳<U+009E>׳•׳“/׳‘׳‘׳<U+009C>׳™/׳<U+009E>׳₪׳¨׳©׳™׳<U+009D>/׳™׳“_׳“׳•׳“/׳‘/׳—׳’׳™׳’׳”/׳—.dar’
```

This is after setting the usual:

```
git config  core.quotepath off
git config  i18n.logoutputencoding utf8
git config  i18n.commitencoding utf8
```

I then tested my UTF-8 setup by:

```
wget -O - http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt
```

and some of the characters were rendered and some weren't.

This is on a Windows 10 system.

Then I installed "Windows Terminal" app (preview, it's still a work in progress) from the Microsoft Store, and then I was able to read the UTF-8-demo.txt file.  (Microsoft has been working on improving UTF-8 support.)

I then created a Git commit message with UTF-8 content and it rendered just fine in Git and in GitLab (https://gitlab.com/atsaloli/test/-/commit/0a2aed5b1986a8e3fdbcf12c90fbe9e737043be5)

So this not an issue with GitLab's support for UTF-8, but an issue with SparkleShare.